# facing issue in XML to WSDL

Tags: php, xml, soap

when I create XML for web service in php I return send array to SOAP UI, but SOAP UI  create reference in XML automatically
e.g

```
<s:something name='test' id='ref1'>
<s:something name='h1' />
<s:something name='h2' />
</s:something>
```

for next same XML

```
<s:something name='test' href='#ref1'>
```

what I want is

```
<s:something name='test'>
<s:something name='h1' />
<s:something name='h2' />
</s:something>

<s:something name='test'>
<s:something name='h1' />
<s:something name='h2' />
</s:something>
```

Comment: And your question is? What means automatically, do you use any programming language?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand it. In general SoapUI will create the XML according to the schema (wsdl) definition. You should not care about those details.

Comment: @home He doesn't want that `id` or `href` field to be added automatically. Even i'm facing the same problem now.
@PoonamBhatt Is the problem solved?

Comment: I found that it is not an issue...it was automatically giving  id='ref1' to the element which is repeating....so when href='#ref1' comes it means it has to refer from id='ref1' element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is not an issue...it was automatically giving id='ref1' to the element which is repeating....so when href='#ref1' comes it means it has to refer from id='ref1' element

Comment: let me know how you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the same objects twice. What PHP produces in the result therefore is* :

> Ok, I have an object here. I call it #1
>
> Oh, I have to return it again. Look at #1 for details

When you want separate arrays, you have to copy the array values before returning it. So instead of

```
$resultArray2[] = $resultArray1[0];
```

You would need to clone the object:

```
#resultArray2[] = clone $resultArray1[0];
```

(Your code might differ, as I've not seen any of your code yet)

---

* at least, that's how I would imagine an internal monologue would sound like :-)